# Passing special characters in a windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, scripting, command, prompt

A program I do not have access to the source of separates a application parameter with | like

```
/targets blah1|blah2
```

I cannot remove the | or the program will crash, but I cannot pass the parameters to the application when having | or the batchscript will either stop immediately, or if I try to run the command via command prompt, it treat blah2 as a command. How do I prevent the blah2 from being processed as a command?

Comment: If you're capturing the arguments to a variable, whenever you retrieve that variable you should do so in the delayed expansion style.  Perhaps if you posted the portion of your script where the crash occurs we could offer more specific advice.

Comment: It's simply

program.exe /targets blah1|blah2 

save in a batch, launch and it will crash.

Dropping the same command in a command prompt will say 
blah2 is not a command

Comment: Oh, so the contents of the .bat file are `program.exe /targets blah1|blah2`?  OK, just stick a caret before the pipe.  `program.exe /targets blah1^|blah2`.  Or you might also try quoting the argument.  `program.exe /targets "blah1|blah2"`